# Issues finding certificates within ingress controller in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure, dns, kubernetes-helm, ingress-nginx

I am trying to deploy some we applications to Kubernetes.

I have an issue mapping the domain into the cluster via the Ingress Controller. When I exec into the ingress controller pod, I can see the following log entries:

```
Error getting SSL certificate "sitecore/global-cd-tls": local SSL certificate sitecore/global-cd-tls was not found. Using default certificate
Error getting SSL certificate "sitecore/global-cm-tls": local SSL certificate sitecore/global-cm-tls was not found. Using default certificate
Error getting SSL certificate "sitecore/global-id-tls": local SSL certificate sitecore/global-id-tls was not found. Using default certificate

processed ingress via admission controller {testedIngressLength:1 testedIngressTime:0.051s renderingIngressLength:1 renderingIngressTime:0.001s admissionTime:26.2kBs testedConfigurationSize:0.052}
"successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="sitecore/sitecore-ingress"
"Found valid IngressClass" ingress="sitecore/sitecore-ingress" ingressclass="nginx"

"Adding secret to local store" name="sitecore/global-cd-tls"
"Adding secret to local store" name="sitecore/global-cm-tls"
"Adding secret to local store" name="sitecore/global-id-tls"
```

Yet the certificates in question have been generated and deployed as secrets in the same name space as the ingress resource and the controller.

I have found similar posts reporting failure to find certificate errors, but I don't get other log entries about errors with certificate type (as with those other posts).

I am using the following to deploy the controller:

```
.\helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx

.\helm repo update

.\helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx `
    --namespace sitecore `
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 `
    --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux `
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux `
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

Example `ingress.yaml` (cd and id removed for brevity):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: sitecore
  name: sitecore-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "32k"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "512m"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cm.globalhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: cm
            port: 
              number: 80
  tls:
  - secretName: global-cm-tls
    hosts:
    - cm.globalhost
```

**I can confirm the following:**

- cm/cd/id pods are deployed and show TRUE for (Initialized/Ready/ContainersReady/PodScheduled)
- `kubectl get ingress` returns (cd.globalhost, cm.globalhost, id.globalhost) with external IP from LB
- `kubectl get services` returns a entry for (nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller LoadBalancer (valid External IP))
- I have ran the script to generate TLS .crt and .key files
- I have deployed the secrets
- I have created a local host entry mapping cm.globalhost to the external load balancer IP address for nginx
- All other pods are healthy
- Everything is deployed to same "sitecore" namespace

**Navigating to site**

When trying to navigate to the URL, Site can't be reached.

Within the ingress pod the following responds with 308 redirect:

```
curl -H "HOST: cm.globalhost" localhost
```